# How to enable button based on both checkbox and textbox content

Tags: jquery

I have the following code :

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" id="Condition" value="Conditions">Conditions<br>
<input type="text" id="txtAgree" disabled>
<input type="submit" name="generate" id="generate" disabled>
</form>

</body>
```

And I wrote the following method in jquery

```
if ($("#Condition").is(":checked")) {
                 $('#txtAgree').prop('disabled',false);
                         $('#txtAgree').keyup(function () {
                             if ($(this).val().length != 0) {
                                  $('#generate').prop('disabled', false);

                             }
                             else {
                                 $('#generate').prop('disabled', true);
                             }
                         })
                     }
                     $('#generate').prop('disabled', false);
                 }
```

But the button getting enabled by checking the checkbox itself. Requirement is if check box is checked,textbox get enabled and if the textbox is not empty, then only button should be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter version for you:

```
$('#Condition,#txtAgree').on('change keyup', function() {
  $('#txtAgree').prop('disabled', !$('#Condition:checked').length);
  $('#generate').prop('disabled', !($('#Condition:checked').length && $('#txtAgree').val()));
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/mt4uokvx/

It listens for both the `keyup` and `change` events on both controls, then enables the text input based on the checkbox and the button based on the checkbox and edit control. In theory it only needs to check the length of the text, but that would require uncheck to clear the text too :)

Answer (score 0):

Your textbox has not the id `txtAgree`. Add this and try like following. Hope this will help you.

```js
$('#Condition').change(function () {
    var txtAgree = $('#txtAgree');
    var generate = $('#generate');

    if (this.checked) {
        txtAgree.prop('disabled', false);
      
        if (txtAgree.val())
            generate.prop('disabled', false);
        else
            generate.prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        txtAgree.prop('disabled', true);
        generate.prop('disabled', true);
    }
});

$('#txtAgree').keyup(function () {
    $('#Condition').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="Condition" value="Conditions">Conditions<br>
<input type="text" id="txtAgree" disabled>
<input type="submit" name="generate" id="generate" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just combine the statements
So,

```
function checkinput(){
   if($("#Condition").is(":checked") && $('#txtAgree').val() != ""){
                 $('#generate').prop('disabled', false);
   } 
   else{
                 $('#generate').prop('disabled', true);
   }
}
```

Then

```
$("#txtAgree").keyup(function(){ 
    checkinput();
});

$("#Condition").change(function(){ 
    if($(this).is(":checked")){  
      $("#txtAgree").prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else{
      $("#txtAgree").prop('disabled', true);
    }

});
```

EDIT: re-disables if criteria not met
EDIT 2: to fit the edited question

Comment: Your example will never enable it again.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I've revised my answer to allow for this

Comment: Missing some brackets somewhere... Can't get it to run as-is. please test your code too :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie thanks, was missing a `);` at the end of `change()`

Comment: Yep, spotted that. Still can't get it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/g3mbw5v1/

Comment: Ah. I see why now. You forgot to enable the text control at all!

Comment: Oh yes, didn't see that the original question was edited

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to combine the events and elements like:

```js
$('#Condition, #txtAgree').on('change keyup', function() {
  if ($('#Condition').is(':checked')) {
    $('#txtAgree').prop('disabled', false);
    if ($('#txtAgree').val().length != 0) {
      $('#generate').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#generate').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  } else {
    $('#txtAgree').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>


<form action="">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Condition" value="Conditions">Conditions<br>
    <input type="text" id="txtAgree" disabled>
    <input type="submit" name="generate" id="generate" disabled>
</form>
```

Comment: This one does not disable the text input again if you uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: True, but you can get the same result in two lines instead of 10 :)

Comment: True... just use a decent debugger instead :)